# C# Xml Serialize Attribute Adding Custom Namespace

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to add namespace during Xml Serialization. So far I have added some of them but I am unable to add custom namespace using Xml serializer.

So far I have achieved this

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2e" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2 imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xs" identifier="test" version="2">
  <lom xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="test lom" xmlns="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM" />
  <resource adlcp:scormtype="sco" />
</manifest>
```

This is my Code

Manifest Class

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "manifest")]
public class Manifest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// manifest root node
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "identifier")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    //[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "adlcp", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    //public string Adlcp = "http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2";

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string SchemaLocation = "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2 imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xs";


    [XmlElement(ElementName = "lom", Namespace = "http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM")]
    public Lom Lom { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("resource")]
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

Lom Class

```
 public class Lom
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string SchemaLocation { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2e")]
        public string Xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";


    }
```

Resource Class

```
 public class Resource
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "scormtype", Namespace = "http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2")]
        public string ScormType { get; set; }
    }
```

My serialization function like this

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Manifest));

        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("xmlns", "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2e");
        ns.Add("adlcp", "http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2");
        ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, data, ns);

        fs.Close();

    }
```

I need output like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <manifest 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    identifier="test" version="2" 
    xmlns:adlcp="test"
    xsi:schemaLocation="test location" 
    **xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2"**>
      <lom 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM lom.xsd" 
      xmlns="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM" />
     <resource adlcp:scormtype="sco"/>
    </manifest>
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: do you definitely need the repeat xsi namespace declaration on the `lom` sub element? I think that part is difficult to do without customising the serialisation, because the declaration is unnecessary (it's already declared on the parent).

Comment: The most immediate thing you need would be `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "manifest", Namespace = "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2")]` ? also `[XmlElement("resource")]` should probably have an explicit `Namespace`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a namspace serializer

```
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Manifest), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, data, ns);
```

and if data is defined as

```
        Manifest data = new Manifest()
        { Identifier = "test", Version = "2", Adlcp = "test", SchemaLocation = "test location" };
        data.Resource = new Resource() { ScormType="sco" };
```

with an attribute

```
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "adlcp", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Adlcp { get; set; }
```

you'll get `xmlns:adlcp="test"` in the output

Same thing for

```
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
```

As well as

```
            ns.Add("adlcp", "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/Manifest/Adlcp");
```

with

```
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "scormtype", Namespace = "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/Manifest/Adlcp")]
    public string ScormType { get; set; }
```

to get a possible `adlcp:scormtype="sco"`

Add a namespace to the root class too, for example

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "manifest", Namespace = "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/Manifest")]
public class Manifest
```

Comment: I tried your code and its perfectly working except one namespace. I am getting two xmlns in root node like this xmlns:xmlns

Comment: I put same namespace but no luck any other idea?

Comment: any idea how to remove xmlns with prefix to just show only xmlns. I am currently have xmlns:xmlns

Comment: No, I'm afraid that this last thing is not possible in a simple and standard way